# custom UI component in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java UI and I have this basic question :

I want to create a custom class which has 3 swing components in it,and then I want to add this components to the UI.

```
class ListItem extends JComponent{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JCheckBox checkbox;
    JLabel label;
    JButton removeBtn;

    public ListItem(String label) {
        this.label = new JLabel();
        this.label.setText(label);

        this.checkbox = new JCheckBox();

        this.removeBtn = new JButton();
        removeBtn.setText("Remove");
    }
}
```

And to add it to UI I am doing this :

```
panelContent = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
this.add(panelContent, BorderLayout.CENTER); //some class which is added to UI

ListItem mItem = new ListItem("todo item 1");
panelContent.add(mItem);
```

but it's not working.It's not adding anything to UI.while the following code is working perfectly:

```
panelContent = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
this.add(panelContent, BorderLayout.CENTER); //some class which is added to UI

JLabel lab = new JLabel();
lab.setText("label");
panelContent.add(lab);
```

Comment: you aren't adding your components (checkbox, label, button) to your custom component. (call `this.add(label);` after creating them.

Comment: @ColinGillespie That needs to be an answer!

Comment: *"I am new to java UI and I have this basic question :"*  What is your question?  I can think of 2 or 3 that might apply, but you choose one and add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16273322/edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are never adding your component of `ListItem` to the the component itself. Moreover, `JComponent` does not have any default `LayoutManager`, so you need to set one.

Could be something like this:

```
class ListItem extends JComponent{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JCheckBox checkbox;
    JLabel label;
    JButton removeBtn;

    public ListItem(String label) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.label = new JLabel();
        this.label.setText(label);

        this.checkbox = new JCheckBox();

        this.removeBtn = new JButton();
        removeBtn.setText("Remove");
        add(checkbox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(this.label);
        add(removeBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson But there was a mistake in my code though: `add(label);` was incorrect and must be `add(this.label);`. Fixed. Thanks for watching. :-)